# Is a question about sport events visiting on or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to get into the Rome for the famous Rome derby, but don't know anything about possibilities of buying the ticket for foreigners, and safety actions on this match.
But I quite unsure about is this question on topic or off-topic.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I would say this is on-topic.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I don't think it's really a problem asking the question first, and only bringing the discussion here afterwards if you see there's (too much) controversy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to get into the Rome for the famous Rome derby, but don't know anything about possibilities of buying the ticket for foreigners

If that's your question, I don't see why it wouldn't be on-topic.  You're essentially asking "How can I go to this place?"  You already know where it is and perhaps your method of travel and other arrangements, but you're looking for more details.  I would not distinguish getting these tickets from getting a visa or a plane ticket.